# Trend of/for? Fashion for?

Tags: prepositions, slang, prepositional-phrases

If I want to say *something has come into fashion*, e.g. cuffed jeans, what do I say?

**There is a new *trend of* cuffed jeans.**

**There is a new *trend for* cuffed jeans.**

**There is *fashion for* cuffed jeans.**

If all variants are incorrect or if there exist variants that are more preferable (used more often), please, write them.

P.S. I guess the 3rd variant is probably incorrect, but it's a literal translation from Russian (which is my native language), so I decided to leave it here too just in case:)

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to say this, I think is - ***"Cuffed Jeans are in style now."***

> [In Style - Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20style)
>
> - popular or fashionable

You could also say -

> **Cuffed Jeans are [trendy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trendy) now.**

I would not use any of your sentences except the first one, which is okay. The 2nd and 3rd sentences definitely sound forced. The 3rd sentence is most likely wrong.
The only way I see ***for*** after fashion is in sentences like **"Fashion for men/women"**.

If you want to use the word *Fashion* use it this way instead:

> **Cuffed Jeans are in fashion now/these days.**

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I see from your examples, the very concept of what I say in Russian most likely doesn't exist in English.

Comment: If the 1st sentence with the "trend of" has a right to exist then (even though it's not the most common way of saying it) it resembles the original phrase most. As I was looking for an expression that can be also used in such sentences as "The trend of ...(cuffed jeans, oversized coats, short haircuts, else) is becoming more & more widespread" or "The trend of ... seems weird/unfeminine/outdated to me".

Comment: Yes, the two sentences in your comment are valid. *"The trend of something is something"* is idiomatic, *"while something is in trend"* is idiomatic too. In fact I deliberately chose not to answer whether the prepositions are correct or not. Because here *of* after trend sounds natural. There are common ways to express these expressions, while some may be grammatically correct, that doesn't necessarily mean they are idiomatic.